# Project information not showing [Delphi 7]

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

The Project > Information option can be quite useful when generating some stats for management, but I note that in some projects the option is greyed out (see images, 1st success, 2nd option not available).

What are the rules for the option being available or not? The help doesn't discuss this, only showing what the items mean when the information is displayed.

[image: Project Information showing]

[image: Project Information option not available]

Comment: What type of project do you open?

Comment: All projects are standard Windows application using a Delphi Project (.dpr) file. One project where information *is* available is quite small (just one form used to program a USB dongle used for licensing and anti-piracy protection). Another project is the full application with dozens of forms, internationalised string resources, tens of thousands of lines of code, etc. This much larger project always has information unavailable, even just after successful compilation.

Comment: I've tried comparing the CFG, DOF and DSK files between the two projects and nothing stands out (like the larger project being specified as part of a project group, for example).

Comment: Wow, who voted this down? Care to undo that please and perhaps leave a comment. This question has not been answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can see Information only for Delphi Project (`*.dpr`) after build (to specify the full path to the project folder, not relative). When you open Delphi package (`*.dpk`) or Project Group (`*.bpg`) then the menuitem "Information for ..." will be disable.

Comment: Unfortunately not the answer. All are Delphi projects (.dpr).